# Find tweets about me

Tags: twitter, search

I'm not using Twitter because until now I didn't see the meaning of using it. On a public website with Twitter integration, I've uploaded a video. The users have re-tweeted my video and I'll like to know what is their comment about. I've searched on Twitter.com using the keyword relevant to my video post but I can't find anything.

Can you give me some tips about how to search on Twitter posts?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find the format of the tweet that the video site generates.

Then find the text that will be consistent across all the tweets - most likely the URL to the video. The only case where it might not be would be if the website tracked referrals and therefore had a unique URL for each user.

Assuming you can find this piece of unique text just search for that using the Twitter web site. You can use the search functionality even if you aren't signed in to Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter search function searches for the keywords that you specify in the entire tweet. So opposite to what people think, it's not just hash tags that make it to the search index of Twitter.

Find a unique "keyword" that would be mentioned in the tweet people would retweet (like an URL) and search for that.

Do mind that it takes some time for Twitter to index all tweets, so it may take some time for your tweet to show up in the search results. (It's pretty much the same with Google, newly created websites won't turn up instantly)